# Spark Dataframe parallel read

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-spark

When using pyspark you can set the number of reduces in the `sc.textFile` method such that you can read a file quicker form S3 as explained [here](http://apache-spark-user-list.1001560.n3.nabble.com/Best-practices-Parallelized-write-to-read-from-S3-td3516.html). This works well, but as of Spark 1.3 we can also start using DataFrames.

Is something like this also possible for Spark DataFrames? I am trying to load them from S3 to a spark cluster (which was created via [ec2-spark](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ec2-scripts.html)). Basically I am trying to get this bit of code to run quick for very large 'data.json' files:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext(CLUSTER_URL, 'ipython-notebook')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.jsonFile('s3n://bucket/data.json').cache()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While waiting for the issue to get fixed I've found a workaround that works for now. The `.json` file contains a dictionary for each row so what I could do is first read it in as an RDD textfile and then cast it into a dataframe by specifying the columns manually:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, Row
sc = SparkContext(CLUSTER_URL, 'ipython-notebook')
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
data = sqlContext.textFile('s3n://bucket/data.json', 30).cache()
df_rdd = data\
    .map(lambda x : dict(eval(x)))\
    .map(lambda x : Row(x1=x['x1'], x2=x['x2'], x3=x['x3'], x4=x['x4']))
df = sqlContext.inferSchema(df_rdd).cache()
```

As per the [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html). This also means that you could use a `.csv` file instead of a json file (which usually saves a lot of disk space) as long as you manually specify the column names in spark.

Answer (score 1):

there's actually a TODO note related to this [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v1.3.1/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/json/JSONRelation.scala#L113) and I created the corresponding [issue here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-7325), so you can up-vote it if that's something you'd need.

Regards,

Olivier.